# (Python sockets), Does not receive everything

Tags: python, sockets, missing-data

i was trying to get the pc's tree send it to the host and save it to a file but, I keep receiving a small part of the tree while it does print out everything on the 'users' side.

Server:

```
conn.send(command.encode(self.FORMAT))
print("[COMMAND SENT] Waiting for execution")
                
msg_length = conn.recv(self.HEADER).decode(self.FORMAT)
final_rcv = conn.recv(int(msg_length)).decode(self.FORMAT)
                
with open(str(adres[0]) + "_" + str(adres[1]) + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(final_rcv)
f.close()
```

client:

```
string_ = ''

for line in tree(Path.home() / ''):
  string_ += line
  string_ += "\n"
                
msg_length = str(len(string_.encode(self.FORMAT)))
self.s.send(msg_length.encode(self.FORMAT))
self.s.send(string_.encode(self.FORMAT))
print(string_)
print(msg_length)
```

Thank you for your time, I hope you can use this is the future.
Edit: There are no errors when I run the code.

Comment: Don't you consider _receiving a small part of the tree_ an error?

Comment: What code are you running?  The code you posted doesn't run (missing imports, establishing connections, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are no errors when I run the code.

While there might be no errors there are return values from the function you call. But you ignore these. Specifically `send` will return the number of bytes actually send, which is not necessarily the same as the size of the data it was asked to send. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send):

> ... Returns the number of bytes sent. **Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent**; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data. ...

As clearly documented, rhe program needs to check the return value of `send` to determine if there are still unwritten data and then `send` these data (and only these) later. Your program does not. Alternatively you can just use [sendall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall):

> ... Unlike send(), this method continues to send data from bytes until either all data has been sent or an error occurs ...

Note that you have the same wrong assumption when calling `recv`. Contrary to your expectation this function is not guaranteed to read the full data but might just read a part. You have to check how much was actually read and if necessary call `recv` again (and maybe again) to read the rest of the data. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv):

> ... The return value is a bytes object representing the data received. The **maximum** amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize.

Comment: thanks, i got it working after i put the receiving end in a loop:

`final_rcv = b""
                
while len(final_rcv) < int(msg_length):
  final_rcv = final_rcv + conn.recv(int(msg_length) - len(final_rcv))
                
final_rcv = final_rcv.decode(self.FORMAT)`

sorry, can't get the enter to work XD